# WebMatrix - US date/time format proving to be an issue

Tags: sql, date, razor, webmatrix

I am creating a UK-based website, so users on my site will typically be used to the format dd/mm/yyyy. I have created a datepicker for the users to use, and it works fine, until i pick the 13th day, (13/10/2013). I'm guessing the database is seeing this as a US date, and thus there are not 13 months in a year.

What do i need to do to my code to convert this to the correct format, or change my databse to use UK format? What's easiest?

```
if(IsPost){
    var dateis = Request["date"];
    var insert = "INSERT INTO TestTable (testdate) VALUES (@0)";
    var qinsert = db.Execute (insert, Request["date"]);
}
}
<div class="container">
<h1>Bootstrap Datepicker</h1>
<form method="post">
<div class="input-append date" id="dp3">
<input class="span2" name="date" size="16" type="text" value="">
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit"/>Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#dp3').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use the format `d MM yyyy` for datepickers (eg '14 November 2013'). It takes up more space, but to me it's more readable and completely sidesteps the `dd/mm/yyyy` vs `mm/dd/yyyy` issue.

If you want to keep it the way it is, as long as your development machine and server machine is correctly configured for UK times, you can use the `AsDateTime()` extension method which should resolve the issue.

```
var qinsert = db.Execute (insert, Request["date"].AsDateTime());
```

As Mike points out in another answer, this isn't best practise though - having code that is reliant on server setup and the like can easily come back to haunt you.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you are best advised storing dates in yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss format. That way there is no problem with regional variations. Also, if your app is global, you might want to consider using UTC so that there are no issues with varying server times.

Comment: but am i right in saying that the database (i'm using sql express, not CE), only stores in US (mm/dd/yyyy)? im all for storing it as you've suggested, but that'll still throw errors when i try and enter it into the database. It tells me i have an "out-of-range value"

Comment: The database internally stores the date in a binary format, not as a formatted string - assuming you're using `datetime2` or `date` as the column type.

Comment: @Gavin, you should read this: http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/solving-datetime-mystery.